# Meaning of a monotone sequence of fucntions?

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, monotone-functions

Dini's theorem:

> if a monotone sequence of continuous functions converges pointwise on
>   a compact space and if the limit function is also continuous, then the
>   convergence is uniform.

What's the meaning of `monotone sequence of functions`?
How can a sequence of functions be monotone? 
If I have a sequence $f_n(x)$, this means that $f_1(x) \le f_2(x) \le f_3(x) \le ... \le f_n(x)$ (Assume increasing) for every $x$?
***Edit:*** Does that mean that for all $x$, $f_1(x) \le f_2(x_1)$ for any $x_1$ or that for all $x$, we fix $x$ and then $f_1(x) \le f_2(x)$?

There is probably a definiton out there, I just couldn't find. Please clear this up for me.

Comment: Looks like a good definition e.g $f_n(x) = \frac{x}{n}$ defines a monotone sequence of functions on [0,1].

Comment: @Paul So in my edit, the second definition (we fix $x$) is the right one, right?

Comment: Yes, it is a pointwise definition and Dini's theorem gives a strong result of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have it right: the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is increasing if $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x$ and all $n$. It is decreasing if $f_n(x)\geq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x$ and all $n$, and monotone if it is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: For all $n$ or for every $n > N$? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Usually for all $n$, but it could be adjusted to all $n>N$ for some fixed $N$ without changing much.

Comment: So I can use Dini's throrem with some fixed $N$? Thing is in Wikipedia they say it needs to be for all $n$.

Comment: I edited my question. I would really appreciate if you take a quick look :)

Comment: The requirement is that for each $x$, $f_n(x)\leq f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $n$ (if the sequence is increasing). It's not too hard to adjust the usual Dini's theorem to the case where the sequence is only increasing for $n>N$; just define a new sequence by $g_n=f_n$ if $n>N$, and $g_n=f_N$ if $n\leq N$.

Comment: This new sequence is increasing, and has the same limit as the original one.